# C - Write to physical memory from kernel module

Tags: c, memory, module, kernel, interrupt

In the kernel module, I need to handle the interrupt by writing a "zero" to address of physical memory.

First of all, I should allocate a memory by some function like "mmap", but for kernel module; for example, ioremap.

```
static irqreturn_t int068_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    unsigned int *p;
    unsigned int address;
    unsigned int memsize;

    address = 0x12345678;
    memsize = 1024;

    p = ioremap(address, memsize);
    p[0]=0;

    printk("Interrupt was handled\n");

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

However, the kernel crashes when interrupt comes and interrupt handler starts handling it
(kernel BUG at mm/vmalloc.c:numberofline)

It seems that something wrong with my usage of ioremap, or I should use another "kernel substitute of mmap"

Please tell me, how to workaround this problem?

Comment: Have you tried doing the `ioremap` call _outside_ the interrupt? E.g. in the module initialization code?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the same code works fine in module init! O_O However, I need this code at interrupt handler

Comment: Does the device keep moving in the physical address space???

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze no, it does not move

Comment: Then why can't you establish the necessary virtual-to-physical mapping just once and only do `p[0]=0;` in the ISR?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Thank you very much for this tip! Now everything is working :-) Please, make it as answer, so I could mark it as "Best"

Comment: dear colleague, I am running into exactly in the same issue, I will glad if could explain here more !

Comment: @user1107855 if I remember correctly, it would be better if you will move stuff like ioremap out of the interrupt handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

directly from Linux `ioremap.c`:

> If you iounmap and ioremap a region, the other CPUs will not see this
>   change until their next context switch. Meanwhile, (eg) if an
>   interrupt comes in on one of those other CPUs which requires the new
>   ioremap'd region to be referenced, the CPU will reference the old
>   region.

This strikly asks to avoid `ioremap` call within an interrupt service routine.

Comment: + [ioremap/iounmap in interrupt context](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg22020.html).